# python variable assignment, can i disable var?

Tags: python, python-3.x

error:

```
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

x is not defined yet...

can i disable x in buttonAritmethic and only enable when I call him?

```
    buttonAritmethic = (x*imgfW)+buttonCenter, 350

    for x in range(buttonReach):
    self.canvasbackground = self.canvasFrame.create_image(buttonAritmethic, anchor = "nw", image = self.imgf)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking... Can you clarify what you mean by 'disable' and 'call' in this context?

Comment: x is not defined yet... but when i do FOR X IN RANGE, x earn a value, and i call buttonAritmethic that contains x, and do error assignment. i know why, because i not defined x before buttonAritmiethc... but i want to not defined x, and ignore the assignment and defined he only i call, have something like: disable buttonAritmethic = blablabla...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make it into a function?

```
def buttonAritmethic(x):
    return (x*imgfW)+buttonCenter, 350
```

Comment: thanks man thats work, but for knowledge now: exist something like disable var?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. Can't refer to it until it exists, that's just how it is. Functions will help you get around it.